# Download replay videos from periscope with wget

Tags: command-line, downloads, wget

I wonder if it's possible to download videos with `wget`. I know there some applications and websites to download from periscope, but can I download replay videos from periscope with `wget`, using only command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is completely possible to download videos using `wget` command. All you need to do is type the video url as the parameter for `wget`:

```
wget http://website.com/videos.mp4
```

**UPDATE**

To download replay videos from Periscope, one will need `youtube-dl`, a tool to download videos from YouTube and few more sites, including Periscope.tv which supported by this tool.

To install `youtube-dl`, run following command:

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Then, copy your desired replay videos link, for example I'll use random videos:

```
youtube-dl -v https://www.periscope.tv/w/1OyKAoBnBmDJb
```

Comment: But it is not working on periscope

Comment: @OzanTemel Updated solution.

Comment: Confirmed and working properly. Thank you very much.